# Using Mongo ODM with Doctrine and Zend Framework 2

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I'm trying to work with ZF2 and Doctrine ORM and MongoDB ODM Module. I have configured correctly ZF2 + Doctrine ORM, but when I add the config of Doctrine MOngoDB ODM Module in ZF2 I get a blank page.

I have observed that If I remove "DoctrineMongoODMModule" from application.config.php file which can find it in /projectDir/config my Application works fine again with Zf2 + Doctrine ORM

```
'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    //'DoctrineMongoODMModule', 
    'Application',
),
```

What happend with my configuration of the DoctrineMongoODMModule in application.config.php file?

Furthermore, to make the configuration of Doctrine MongoDB ODM Module, I have the file module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php with the next code:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server'  => 'localhost',
                'port'    => '27017',
                'dbname'  => 'testDB',
                'options' => array(
                    )
                ),
            ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',
                'driver'             => 'odm_default',
                'generate_proxies'   => true,
                'proxy_dir'          => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',
                'generate_hydrators' => true,
                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator',
                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',
                'default_db'         => 'testDB',
                'filters'            => array(),  // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class'),
                'logger'             => null // 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Logging\DebugStack'
                )
            ),
        'driver' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'class'     => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'namespace' => 'Application\Document',
                    'paths'     => array('module/Application/src/Application/Document'),
                    )
                ),              
            ),
        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'connection'    => 'odm_default',
                'configuration' => 'odm_default',
                'eventmanager'  => 'odm_default'
                )
            ),
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array(
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
    );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you pay attention to the code indentation above you can see an extra closing bracket `),` at line 11 (in the code above, your editor may differ). Try removing that line, it's probably what's causing the whitescreen since php won't be able to parse it.

Comment: I have remove the extra bracket... but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Crisp is right, i just removed that line and re-indented the code. Another detail is, you should turn display_errors to on in php.ini, also check your http server's error.log file to figure out what happening. Nobody can help without an exact error message.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers. I have activated the posibility to see the errors and when I try to load the home page of my  web application I've got the error that you can see in other answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have been abandoned. Essential information was (incorrectly) added as an answer, and this information was not edited into the question after being deleted by reviewers in the Review Queue. Could also be closed as lacking an [mcve].